# Create a sequence based on two grouped fields with repeating values

Tags: sas

I have a data set with an ID and Date/Time field along with other fields such as name etc. Each record has a policy Id. And a policy can have multiple transactions represented here by the records with changing date/time. Some transactions can have multiple records shown in the example as records with the exact same date/time and ID.

Example: 
Id       Date 
1        06/07/2018 10:54:31 
1        06/07/2018 10:54:31 
1        10/10/2018 15:10:65 
1        11/11/2018 17:10:42 
2        05/01/2018 12:10:42 
2        08/07/2018 12:10:42 
2        10/10/2018 15:10:65 
2        11/11/2018 10:10:42 
2        11/11/2018 10:10:42

I want to add a sequence number based on both the Id and Date/Time field which doesn’t increment when the Date/Time field remains the same grouping records with the same value.

Output Wanted:
**Example2**: 
| Id   | Date.  | **Sequence** | 
|:-- |:--------------------:| -----:| 
| 1    | 06/07/2018 10:54:31    |   1 | 
| 1    | 06/07/2018 10:54:31    |   1 | 
| 1    | 10/10/2018 15:10:65    |   2 | 
| 1    | 11/11/2018 17:10:42    |   3 | 
| 2    | 05/01/2018 12:10:42    |   1 | 
| 2    | 05/01/2018 12:10:42    |   1 | 
| 2    | 10/10/2018 15:10:65    |   2 | 
| 2    | 11/11/2018 10:10:42    |   3 | 
| 2    | 11/11/2018 10:10:42    |   3 |

The code I’ve been attempting to use is based around LAST and FIRST statements but to no avail.

DATA Test; 
SET Example1; 
BY Id DateTime; 
RETAIN Sequence 0; 
IF First.Id THEN Sequence +1;

.... this is as far as I’ve got...pretty useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very, very close.

1. At each first of the ID (first.ID) you set the counter to 0 or 1
2. At the first of each date (first.dateTime), increment your sequential counter.

   ```
   DATA Test;
       SET Example1;
       BY Id DateTime;
       RETAIN Sequence 0;

       IF First.Id THEN Sequence=0;
       if first.dateTime then sequence+1;

   run;
   ```